# How to increase RGB darkness?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, rgb, haxe

I am trying to increase darkness of RGB using pure math without relying on any framework ..

So, here is my implementation:

Provided with R, G, B ( each from 0 to 256 ) & darknessFactor ( 0 to 1 )

```
// this is a pseudocode
r*= darknessFactor;
g*= darknessFactor;
b*= darknessFactor;

r= int (r);
g= int (g);
b= int (b);

g <<= 8;
r <<= 16;

final_color= b + g  + r ;
```

Then, when I tried to use it against R= 00, G= 256, B= 0, darknessFactor= 0.1, I get a result near to dark red!

Any idea?

EDIT

Would ColorTransform of actionScript 3 solve this problem?

Comment: Is shifting a floating-pointer number (25.6) defined in ActionScript?

Comment: I am using haxe, but I added ActionScript tag to get more knowledgeable people in colors ..

Comment: What the final_color value do you get?

Comment: maximum values should be 255, not 256. Setting G=256 is equivalent of setting R=1 and G=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, your pseudo-code looks good, so there must be a problem in your actual code. Although it is really strange that you would have a red result with a green input. With your code, that would be possible for a factor bigger than one, because you're not clamping the channels, so the green channel could overflow into the red one.

This will work:

```
function clamp(channel:Float) {
  var v = Std.int(channel);
  return 
    if (v < 0) 0;
    else if (v > 0xFF) 0xFF;
    else v;
}
function darken(color:Int, factor:Float) {
  var r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
  var g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
  var b = color & 0xFF;

  return 
    (clamp(r * factor) << 16)
    + (clamp(g * factor) << 8)
    + clamp(b * factor);
}
```

You can test it here: http://try.haxe.org/#b328e

Answer (score 1):

you should use HSV intead of RGB.

first, RGB convert to HSV.

second, decrease v(brightness[0 to 1]).

finally, HSV convert to RGB.

you can easily implement converting program.
or, can find library.

Answer (score 0):

ColorTransform would be the simplest way to solve this problem without writing any new code.

See [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e16.html).

The multiplier properties would be what you want in order to darken the current colour.

```
var colorInfo:ColorTransform = myDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform; 

// Make some color transformations here.
// Reduce colour by 10%
colorInfo.redMultiplier = 0.9; 
colorInfo.greenMultiplier = 0.9; 
colorInfo.blueMultiplier = 0.9; 

// Commit the change. 
myDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = colorInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

For an RGB(R1,G1,B1), the new RGB(R2,G2,B2) darkened by the percentage/factor of p% should be:

```
    R2 = R1 - (R1/100)*P
    G2 = G1 - (G1/100)*P
    B2 = B1 - (B1/100)*P
```

This is only the solution to your specific problem. If you want to work on something more advanced then please have a look at HSL color space and how to work with its L factor.